# C++. Видит/не видит дружественную функцию при разных сигнатурах

Tags: c++, дружественная-функция

win10, visual studio 2022.

some.h

```
всякие инклуды
template<typename T>
class MyClass{
    ...
    friend void some_fu1();
    friend void some_fu2(MyClass<int>& c);
};
void some_fu1();
```

есть так же some.cpp файл в котором реализованы дружественные функции, файл main.h в котором происходит инклуд some.h

main.cpp

```
всякие инклуды 
void main(){
    MyClass<int> c1
    some_fu1();
    some_fu2(c1)
}
```

Все работает нормально если в some.h происходит объявление функции some_fu1, иначе IDE её не видит (идентификатор не определен), но some_fu2 там не объявлена и все норм работает. Подскажите что я упустил в понимании того как работают дружественные функции, и возможно именно когда параметром является шаблонный специализированный класс? Ведь разница только в сигнатуре. Исправив сигнатуру у some_fu1, то есть добавив туда параметр как в some_fu2, из some.h можно убрать объявление функции some_fu1. Это какая та особенность?
То есть буквально разница только в сигнатуре функции. В других файлах нет схожих названий функций, то что влияет именно когда параметром функции является класс к которому дружественна данная функция проверил тем, что делал другие параметры и функция снова не видна для IDE в main.cpp.
Заранее спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`friend`-функции, если не объявлены дополнительно снаружи класса, обнаруживаются только [аргументозависимым поиском](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

В `some_fu2(c1);`, поскольку аргумент типа `MyClass`, то friend-ы оттуда учитываются.

В `some_fu1();` аргументов нет, поэтому friend-ы из `MyClass` и других классов не учитываются.

Comment: спасибо большое, это сравни тому как "открыть глаза" :)